# I can't upload screenshots to the new iTunes Connect Media Manager

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot, media-manager

As for August 8th 2016 Apple has changed it's requirement about Screenshoots. Now only one set of screenshots per device family is required.

This should simplify the process, however, the "choose file" option is disabled:
[image: Can't upload screenshots]

As you can see the app status is "Prepare for submission" and there is a build ready.

I tried using Google Chrome and Safari. It doesn't appear to be browser related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this by changing main language of `iTunes` record. Please find the below steps.

1. Copy your app description and keywords to `notepad`.
2. Go to app information
3. In the right side clic on language and select the language you specified in `XCode` as main language(Localization Native development Region).
4. Delete unwanted language configurations from the same input.
5. Go to your build and add description, keywords. Choose file for screenshots `5.5` should be available now.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying for a long time to upload, but strange error appeared. Here is the screen from the debug console: [image]:

I read, that it is because of wrong language and some other assumptions. But...

What fixed it was to login into itunesconnect via Safari. Not with Chrome like i did it before.

Comment: Switch to Safari. Don't use Chrome.

Comment: @Rayfleck i use the android device and like chrome synchronization and password autocompletions. Also i think its safer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with iTunes connect and changing the language didn't work for me. My solution was to make a new app on iTunes connect and the choose file button was enabled. You cannot delete the current app as it hasn't been approved yet, so change the bundle identifier of the current one and save it. This way you can create a new app with the same identifier.